# Export to CSV PHP as a Download File

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, fputcsv

I am using a CSV file to export a mysql table. How can I view it as a download file now that it is stored on Drive `C:` directly without any notification

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // <--  db address
$user = 'root'; // <-- db user name
$pass = 'root'; // <-- password
$db = 'urs'; // db's name
$table = 'veiwresult'; // table you want to export
$file = 'alaa'; // csv name.
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT ApplicantNum,name, averg,choice FROM veiwresult");
fputcsv($f, array('ApplicantNum','name','averg', 'choice'));
$timestamp = date('Ymd-His'); 

$f = fopen("C:/mycsv-{$timestamp}.csv", 'w');
// Headers    
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
fputcsv($f, $row);
}


fputcsv($f, $items_array);
fclose($f);

?>
```

Comment: What do you want? To save exported file on a hosting disk c:\bla.csv? Do you want to save the file onto client`s disk c:? What`s the problem?

Comment: i want to down lode file in any place that user choiec  and then open it

Comment: like header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"alaa.csv\"");
how i can use it hear

Comment: How did you get on with this? Did you get it working in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store csv-file and then open it without any clicking, it`s impossible.

If you just wish to have it opened, open it in browser window via

```
header('Content-disposition: inline;filename=foobar.csv');
header('Content-Type: text/csv;charset=UTF-8');
echo $csv_content;
```

where $csv_content is a string with contents of csv-file. You cat get it this way

```
$csv_content = file_get_contents('c:/mycsv.csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

To download it...

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost'; // <--  db address
$user = 'root'; // <-- db user name
$pass = 'root'; // <-- password
$db = 'urs'; // db's name
$table = 'veiwresult'; // table you want to export
$file = 'alaa'; // csv name.
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT ApplicantNum,name, averg,choice FROM veiwresult");
fputcsv($f, array('ApplicantNum','name','averg', 'choice'));
$timestamp = date('Ymd-His'); 

$f = fopen("C:/mycsv-{$timestamp}.csv", 'w');
// Headers    
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
fputcsv($f, $row);
}

fputcsv($f, $items_array);
fclose($f);

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mycsv-{$timestamp}"');
readfile('C:/mycsv-{$timestamp}.csv');
?>
```

This will still notify the user of the download, and depending on their settings they may need to accept the download. This functionality cannot be overridden of course.